# Atom-editor customize autocompletes/suggestions

Tags: autocomplete, code-snippets, atom-editor

How can I change the autocomplete in Atom so `input` becomes

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{cursor here}">
```

instead of the default

```
<input type="{'button'|cursor here}" name="name" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete as you describe it is called a [snippet](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/) in GitHub Atom's terminology.  You can change these by overriding the *input* snippet provided by the [language-html](https://github.com/atom/language-html/blob/master/snippets/language-html.cson) package that ships with Atom.

User defined Snippets are stored in your Atom profile which you can access by going to `File` -> `Snippets...`, this will open the file in the editor you can then paste the following at end of the file

```coffee
'.text.html':
  'Input':
    'prefix': 'input'
    'body': '<input type="text" name="${1:name}">$0'
```

Make sure you save the file before testing our your updated snippet in a document that has HTML Selected as it's language.